# Nested functions in EE python API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, google-earth-engine-python-api

I am trying to divide a feature collection into a mosaic of different cells in order to aid with exporting over a large area. I found [the following script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/f08e5aa713df9413a4e33dd02b613353) which is mentioned in [this stack overflow question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/352017/create-within-country-grids-for-multiple-countries-at-once-in-google-earth-engin) to divide a geometry into bite-sized areas and I am trying to convert it to Python so that I can export data in an iterative fashion.

I have considered [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/365121/how-to-nest-mapped-functions-with-the-earth-engine-python-api) and [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/365121/how-to-nest-mapped-functions-with-the-earth-engine-python-api), but neither seem to adequately capture the complexity of the above script. The issue pertains to how python treats scope and I have tried doing a (rather dumb) method of carrying variables as arguments through each  and every function, but this breaks down when we are forced to use `.map()`

Here is my naive approach to translating between the two (mostly converted using `geemap:: js_snippet_to_py()` function.

```
def tile(region, size_in_degrees):
    def tile_geometry(geometry):
        coords = ee.List(geometry.bounds().coordinates().get(0))
        min_point = ee.List(coords.get(0))
        max_point = ee.List(coords.get(2))

        def sequence(direction):
            start = min_point.get(direction)
            stop = ee.Number(max_point.get(direction))
            return ee.List.sequence(start, stop, size_in_degrees)

        def build_numbers(y):
            return ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Rectangle([[ee.Number(x), ee.Number(y)], \
                [ee.Number(x).add(size_in_degrees).min(max_point.get(0)), \
                  ee.Number(y).add(size_in_degrees).min(max_point.get(1)) \
                ]]).intersection(geometry, 30))
        
        def func_nyp(x):
            return sequence(1).map(build_numbers)
        
        tiles = sequence(0).map(func_nyp).flatten()

    return ee.FeatureCollection(tiles).filterBounds(geometry)

    def tile_feature_collection(feature_collection):
        return ee.FeatureCollection(
          feature_collection.iterate(iterate_func))
    
    def iterate_func(feature, acc):
        return ee.FeatureCollection(acc).merge(tile_geometry(ee.Feature(feature).geometry())), ee.FeatureCollection([])


     if (isinstance(region, ee.FeatureCollection)):
        return tile_feature_collection(region)
    elif (isinstance(region, ee.Feature)):
        return tile_geometry(region.geometry())
    elif (isinstance(region,ee.Geometry)):
        return tile_geometry(region)
    else:
        print('region must be ee.FeatureCollection, ee.Feature, or ee.Geometry. Was ' + str(region))
```

When I run the above code, the `sequence()` function is not known to the global environment. However, when I try to extract each of the nested functions, I quickly run into issues surrounding variables that need to be carried through from others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried running the code, but here are the translation mistakes I see.

---

```py
return ee.FeatureCollection(sequence(0).map(func_nyp).flatten()).filterBounds(geometry)
```

should be indented one more level so that it is part of `tile_geometry` (in which `sequence` is defined) instead of part of `tile` (where `sequence` is out of scope).

It also could be simplified by using the variable you defined,

```py
return ee.FeatureCollection(tiles).filterBounds(geometry)
```

but that won't change the behavior.

---

```py
def build_numbers(y):
    return ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Rectangle([[ee.Number(x), ee.Number(y)], \
        [ee.Number(x).add(size_in_degrees).min(max_point.get(0)), \
          ee.Number(y).add(size_in_degrees).min(max_point.get(1)) \
        ]]).intersection(geometry, 30))

def func_nyp(x):
    return sequence(1).map(build_numbers)
```

Here `build_numbers` uses `x`, so it needs to be defined where `x` is:

```py
def func_nyp(x):
    def build_numbers(y):
        return ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Rectangle([[ee.Number(x), ee.Number(y)],
            [ee.Number(x).add(size_in_degrees).min(max_point.get(0)),
              ee.Number(y).add(size_in_degrees).min(max_point.get(1))
            ]]).intersection(geometry, 30))

    return sequence(1).map(build_numbers)
```

I also removed the backslashes — they are unnecessary in Python whenever there are parentheses or brackets around the expression.

General advice: don't assume you can make functions *less* nested than they were, unless you've examined them to ensure they don't use any outer variables.

Also remember that you can use Python `lambda` expressions instead of named functions to write functions in-line as in JavaScript, though they can be harder to read.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I originally changed that line because I thought it would help me deal with the scope issues. After indenting the return statement, I am still running into issues, particularly in the `func_nyp()` function and its nestedness with `build_numbers`.

Comment: @SeanCarter I've added a section on that problem.